# How to use absolute positioning without overlap effect

Tags: css, absolute, overlapping

So, I'm using a *while loop* with PHP. The while loop makes the following code:

```
<img src='$user_six' class='avatar_friend'>
```

Please don't worry about `$user_six` or the background info on the while loop. I **know** it works. I'm trying to put three avatars on top of a movie. The problem is that each image takes space and is ruining the spacing with the movies.

[image: Visual Aid of Project]

This is the information of `.avatar_friend`:

```
.avatar_friend {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

I think absolute positioning works better, but the images overlap each other.

[image: Second Part of Question]

This is the information of `.avatar_friend`:

```
.avatar_friend {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

How can I have the best of both positions? I want proper spacing, but no overlapping. **How can I achieve this effect?**

**EDIT:**

I've tried doing the following:

**html**

```
<div id='container'> <img src='$user_six' class='avatar_friend'> </div>
```

**css**

```
#container {
position: absolute;
}

.avatar_friend {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

This did not work...

[image: Visual Aid of what I've tried]

**EDIT 2:**

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Movies </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='main.css'>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src='main.js'></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Navigation -->
      <div id='nav'>
         <!-- Profile Wrapper -->
      <ul class="profile-wrapper">
            <li>
                <!-- user profile -->
                <div class="profile">
                    <img src="avatars/default.png" />
                    <a href="#" class="name"> MatthewMalan <i class="fa fa-caret-down" id="caret-down"></i></a>

                    <!-- more menu -->
                    <ul class="menu">
                      <a href="#"><li>Sign Out</li></a>
                        <a href="#"><li>Sign Out</li></a>
                        <a href="logout.php"><li>Sign Out</li></a>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    <!-- End of Profile Wrapper -->
      </div>
    <!-- End of Navigation -->

    <!-- Movie Content -->
      <div id='movie_content2'>
        <div id='movie_line'>
          <div id='movie_line2'></div>

          <!-- Dropdown Selection -->

          <nav>
          <ul id="dropdown_selection">
            <li><a href="#">Most Recent</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="http://localhost/Drop%20Box/movies.php?page=1&sorting=popular"> &nbsp; Most Liked </a></li>
                <li><a href="http://localhost/Drop%20Box/movies.php?page=1&sorting=history"> &nbsp; My History </a></li>
                <li><a href="http://localhost/Drop%20Box/movies.php?page=1&sorting=likes"> &nbsp; My Likes </a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
          <!-- End of Dropdown Selection -->

         <div id='descriptive_div' number='1'> <i class='fa fa-caret-left' id='descriptive_caret' number='1'></i> <a href='like.php?number=7&page=1'><a href='like.php?number=7&page=1&code=1&sorting=recent'> <div class='like_button' number='1'> Like </div> </a></a> <span id='descriptive_div_text'> Professional, Clean, Ready to Go </span> <div id='files_left'> 3 Copies Left </div> </div><a href='open.php?destination=movies/56c7ede7d3ed3658.44679765.mp4'> <div class='movie_length' number='1'> <div id='movie_length_text' number='1'> 1h 20m </div> </div> </a><a href='open.php?destination=movies/56c7ede7d3ed3658.44679765.mp4'> <div class='movie_rating3' number='1'> <span id='movie_rating_text' number='1'> G </span> </div> </a><a href='open.php?destination=movies/56c7ede7d3ed3658.44679765.mp4'> <img src='covers/inside.jpg' class='movie_size' number='1'> </a><div id='descriptive_div' number='2'> <i class='fa fa-caret-left' id='descriptive_caret' number='2'></i> <a href='like.php?number=8&page=1'><a href='like.php?number=8&page=1&code=1&sorting=recent'> <div class='like_button' number='2'> Like </div> </a></a> <span id='descriptive_div_text'> s </span> <div id='files_left'> 1 Copy Left </div> </div><a href='open.php?destination=movies/56c7ede7d3ed3108.44679765.mp4'> <div class='movie_length' number='2'> <div id='movie_length_text' number='2'> 2h 16m </div> </div> </a><a href='open.php?destination=movies/56c7ede7d3ed3108.44679765.mp4'> <div class='movie_rating' number='2'> <span id='movie_rating_text' number='2'> PG-13 </span> </div> </a><a href='open.php?destination=movies/56c7ede7d3ed3108.44679765.mp4'> <img src='covers/star wars.jpg' class='movie_size' number='2'> </a><img src='avatars/sam.jpg' class='avatar_friend'><img src='avatars/traek.jpg' class='avatar_friend'><img src='avatars/jessie.jpg' class='avatar_friend'><div id='descriptive_div' number='3'> <i class='fa fa-caret-left' id='descriptive_caret' number='3'></i> <a href='like.php?number=9&page=1'><a href='like.php?number=9&page=1&sorting=recent'> <div class='liked_button' number='3'> Like </div> </a></a> <span id='descriptive_div_text'> r </span> <div id='files_left'> 7 Copies Left </div> </div><a href='open.php?destination=movies/56e06853166618.33290858.mp4'> <div class='movie_length' number='3'> <div id='movie_length_text' number='3'> r </div> </div> </a><a href='open.php?destination=movies/56e06853166618.33290858.mp4'> <div class='movie_rating4' number='3'> <span id='movie_rating_text' number='3'> PG-13 </span> </div> </a><a href='open.php?destination=movies/56e06853166618.33290858.mp4'> <img src='covers/56e068530dc9f9.52895782.jpg' class='movie_size3' number='3'> </a><br><div class="complete_page">1</div>        </div>
      </div>
    <!-- End of Movie Content -->
  </body>
</html>
```

**css**

```
/* Rating of Movie Content */

.movie_rating, .movie_rating2, .movie_rating3, .movie_rating4, .movie_rating5, .movie_rating6, .movie_length, .movie_length2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #E10E0D;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  font-family: 'Days One', sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    border: 1px solid #FE4042;
}

.movie_rating4, .movie_rating5, .movie_rating6 {
 background: #7D5505;
 border: 1px solid #F9BA01;
}

.movie_length, .movie_length2 {
  width: 120px;
  background: #02477D;
  border: 1px solid #97D0F2;
  margin-top: 239px;
}

.movie_length2 {
  width: 75px;
}

.movie_rating2, .movie_rating5 {
  width: 60px;
}

.movie_rating3, .movie_rating6 {
  width: 40px;
}

#movie_rating_text, #movie_length_text {
  font-size: 25px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  font-family: 'Days One', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

/* Description of Movie */

#descriptive_div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  min-height: 241px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  z-index: 6;
  margin-left: 228px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  border: 5px solid #ccc;
  display: none;
}

#descriptive_div_text {
  width: 370px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 14px;
  top: 14px;
  text-align: left;
}

#descriptive_caret {
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 51px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -19px;
  margin-top: 115px;
  display: none;
}

/* End of Description of Movie */

/* Movie Line */

#movie_line2 {
  width: 1px;
  height: 635px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1120px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 2;
}

/* End of Movie Line */


/* End of Rating of Movie Content */

/* Like Button */

.like_button, .liked_button {
  background: #0566AE;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 3px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -95px;
  z-index: 6;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Days One', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.liked_button {
  background: #2C599D;
  margin-left: -95px;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.like_button:hover {
  background: #2C599D;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* End of Like Button */

/* End of Movie Content */

/* Tab System for admin.php */

h1, h2, h3, h4 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: .1rem 0;
  border-left: 4px solid #4F2CCA;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.material-tabs {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 16px;
  padding-top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 480px;
  left: calc(50% - 480px/2);
  position: relative;
  margin: 96px auto;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23) !important;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
  .material-tabs {
    max-width: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
}

.visible {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .35s ease;
  transition: opacity .35s ease;
  z-index: 3;
}

.hidden {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0s ease;
  transition: opacity 0s ease;
}
.hidden img {
  display: none;
}

[class*="tabbed-section-"] {
  float: left;
  color: #000;
}
[class*="tabbed-section-"] img {
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto 10%;
}

.tabbed-section__selector {
  position: relative;
  height: 32px;
  top: -31.2px;
  left: -16px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.tabbed-section__selector [class*="-tab-"] {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.tabbed-section__selector [class*="-tab-"].active {
  color: #4F2CCA;
}
.tabbed-section__selector a:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 2px;
}
.tabbed-section__selector a:last-of-type {
  border-top-right-radius: 2px;
}

.tabbed-section__highlighter {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: #4F2CCA;
  max-width: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
          transform: translateX(0);
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.23s ease;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.23s ease;
  transition: transform 0.23s ease;
  transition: transform 0.23s ease, -webkit-transform 0.23s ease;
}

.tabbed-section__selector-tab-3.active ~ .tabbed-section__highlighter {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(200px);
          transform: translateX(200px);
}

.tabbed-section__selector-tab-2.active ~ .tabbed-section__highlighter {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100px);
          transform: translateX(100px);
}

.tabbed-section__selector-tab-1.active ~ .tabbed-section__highlighter {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
          transform: translateX(0);
}

.divider {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}



/* End of Tab system for admin.php */

/* Create */

#title, #length {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 11px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 400px;
}

#title:focus, #description:focus, #length:focus {
  border: 1px solid #A9A9A9;
}

#description {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 11px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 400px;
  resize: vertical;
  max-height: 70px;
}

#rating_text {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
}

#length_text {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
}

/* End of Create */

/* Dropdown Selection */

nav {
  margin: 10rem auto;
  width: 220px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1150px;
  top: -140px;
}

nav ul {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

nav a {
  background: #1A1A1A;
  color: inherit;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1rem;
}

nav ul ul a:hover {
  background: #666;
}

nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
}

nav ul:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

nav ul:first-child:hover > li:first-child:before {
  border: .7rem solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #fff;
}

nav ul ul > li:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

nav ul > li:first-child:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
}

nav ul:first-child > li:first-child:before {
  border: .7rem solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #fff;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 175px;
  top: 30px;
}


.fa {
  margin-right: .5rem;
}

/* End of Dropdown Selection */

/* Files Left */

#files_left {
  color: red;
  width: 110px;
  padding: 1px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10%;
  position: relative;
  left: 15px;
  top: 20px;
}

/* End of Files Left */

/* Avatar */

.avatar_friend {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

/* End of Avatar */
```

Some of the CSS may be for other pages. I realize this is a lot of information. Let me know if you need anything else...

Comment: would be best to wrap the images in a container which gets the `absolute` positioning and gives you more control.

Comment: I've tried this. I've edited my answers to explain...

Comment: Can you get your browser so that it shows what's pictured, then right-click, say View page source (or whatever it is for your browser) and then copy and paste that into the HTML? Right now I don't see three of anything much in what you've provided.

Comment: I've already tried @LGSon solution. It doesn't work for my particular situation. All of these movies are dynamic, so the HTML is through PHP. The PHP has three while loops...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you use the same `id` in 6 elements for every movie, which you shouldn't. An `id` is unique, so change that to like `'descriptive_div_1', 'descriptive_caret_1', etc` (I did that in the samples below so you can see where).

This is how a movie section looks like (repeated for each movie, no wrapper around each of them)

```
<div id='descriptive_div_2' number='2'> 
  <i class='fa fa-caret-left' id='descriptive_caret_2' number='2'></i> 
  <a href='like.php?number=8&page=1'>
    <a href='like.php?number=8&page=1&code=1&sorting=recent'> 
      <div class='like_button' number='2'> Like </div> 
    </a>
  </a> 
  <span id='descriptive_div_text_2'> s </span> 
  <div id='files_left_2'> 1 Copy Left </div> 
</div>
<a href='open.php?destination=movies/56c7ede7d3ed3108.44679765.mp4'> 
  <div class='movie_length' number='2'> 
    <div id='movie_length_text_2' number='2'> 2h 16m </div> 
  </div> 
</a>
<a href='open.php?destination=movies/56c7ede7d3ed3108.44679765.mp4'> 
  <div class='movie_rating_2' number='2'> 
    <span id='movie_rating_text_2' number='2'> PG-13 </span> 
  </div> 
</a>
<a href='open.php?destination=movies/56c7ede7d3ed3108.44679765.mp4'> 
  <img src='covers/star wars.jpg' class='movie_size' number='2'>
</a>
<img src='avatars/sam.jpg' class='avatar_friend'>
<img src='avatars/traek.jpg' class='avatar_friend'>
<img src='avatars/jessie.jpg' class='avatar_friend'>
```

So to be able to target each `avatar_friend` in each movie section, you need CSS rules like this

```
.avatar_friend {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

div[number] + a + a + a ~ .avatar_friend:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
  left: 0px;
}
div[number] + a + a + a ~ .avatar_friend:nth-of-type(3n+2) {
  left: 36px;
}
div[number] + a + a + a ~ .avatar_friend:nth-of-type(3n+3) {
  left: 72px;
}
```

The problem with this is you need to know how many `avatars_friend`'s it is, as you need to change the `nth-of-type` counter and the amount of CSS rules accordingly.

---

By adding a wrapper like this for the avatar's, will fix it for you

```
<div id='descriptive_div_2' number='2'> 
  <i class='fa fa-caret-left' id='descriptive_caret_2' number='2'></i> 
  <a href='like.php?number=8&page=1'>
    <a href='like.php?number=8&page=1&code=1&sorting=recent'> 
      <div class='like_button' number='2'> Like </div> 
    </a>
  </a> 
  <span id='descriptive_div_text_2'> s </span> 
  <div id='files_left_2'> 1 Copy Left </div> 
</div>
<a href='open.php?destination=movies/56c7ede7d3ed3108.44679765.mp4'> 
  <div class='movie_length' number='2'> 
    <div id='movie_length_text_2' number='2'> 2h 16m </div> 
  </div> 
</a>
<a href='open.php?destination=movies/56c7ede7d3ed3108.44679765.mp4'> 
  <div class='movie_rating_2' number='2'> 
    <span id='movie_rating_text_2' number='2'> PG-13 </span> 
  </div> 
</a>
<a href='open.php?destination=movies/56c7ede7d3ed3108.44679765.mp4'> 
  <img src='covers/star wars.jpg' class='movie_size' number='2'>
</a>
<div class='avatar_friend_wrapper'>
  <img src='avatars/sam.jpg' class='avatar_friend'>
  <img src='avatars/traek.jpg' class='avatar_friend'>
  <img src='avatars/jessie.jpg' class='avatar_friend'>
</div>
```

```
.avatar_friend_wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.avatar_friend {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

---

What I recommend to do, would be to change your PHP loops so they generate something like this instead, where each movie item has its own wrapper.

With that you get a completely different control how to layout each movie info item based on screen size etc.

```
<div class='movie_div_2' number='2'> 
  <div id='descriptive_div_2' number='2'> 
    <i class='fa fa-caret-left' id='descriptive_caret_2' number='2'></i> 
    <a href='like.php?number=8&page=1'>
      <a href='like.php?number=8&page=1&code=1&sorting=recent'> 
        <div class='like_button' number='2'> Like </div> 
      </a>
    </a> 
    <span id='descriptive_div_text_2'> s </span> 
    <div id='files_left_2'> 1 Copy Left </div> 
  </div>
  <a href='open.php?destination=movies/56c7ede7d3ed3108.44679765.mp4'> 
    <div class='movie_length' number='2'> 
      <div id='movie_length_text_2' number='2'> 2h 16m </div> 
    </div> 
  </a>
  <a href='open.php?destination=movies/56c7ede7d3ed3108.44679765.mp4'> 
    <div class='movie_rating_2' number='2'> 
      <span id='movie_rating_text_2' number='2'> PG-13 </span> 
    </div> 
  </a>
  <a href='open.php?destination=movies/56c7ede7d3ed3108.44679765.mp4'> 
    <img src='covers/star wars.jpg' class='movie_size' number='2'>
  </a>
  <div class='avatar_friend_wrapper'>
    <img src='avatars/sam.jpg' class='avatar_friend'>
    <img src='avatars/traek.jpg' class='avatar_friend'>
    <img src='avatars/jessie.jpg' class='avatar_friend'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have a unique problem due to doing this code with a PHP while loop. I can't do code outside of this while loop. All code must be inside of the while loop, so whatever code you give me will be duplicated three times. So, there will be three divs with a class of movie and three divs with a class of avatar and wrapper and three images. Do you have any solution that can be repeated like this? I realize this is difficult...

Comment: @ProgrammingTree Please post a bigger chunk of your rendered html so I can see how it looks like

Comment: I don't want to lose you with complex PHP code. I have three while loops, one that checks for the likes of a movie, then the friends of the users that share similar likes and then the details of the user. That is why I can't put code outside of the while loop. Normally I could, but I'm dealing with three while loops. In regards to the HTML, what part of the code do you want? These avatars are not children of the movies. Do you want to possibly make them children of the movies through absolute values?

Comment: @ProgrammingTree So how is the avatars related to a certain movie? ... and for me to tell how to structure your CSS, I need to see the rendered html. Your posted screen dumps shows 3 movies, how does that markup look like in the browser?

Comment: Users can send friend requests to other users. If you like a movie and some of your friends like the same movie, the friends avatar will be shown on that particular movie. I'll post the markup in my question...

Comment: @ProgrammingTree Updated my answer again. If this doesn't help you out, let me know and I delete my answer right away.

Comment: My solution resulted in using JQuery and the CSS property. However, for the normal user, your solution was perfect was met every requirement. Most users aren't dealing with three while loops. I'm impressed you attempted to solve the problem with the idea of three while loops being an obstacle. I will give you the accepted answer for this reason...

Comment: @ProgrammingTree Thanks and perfect you found a way.